# What happens when I pipe any command to a telnet session , why does the session closes

Tags: bash, shell, telnet

What happens when I pipe any command to a telnet session , why does the session closes . How can I give a command which can be processes instead of closeing the connection .

I am trying

echo "xvz" | telnet 0 abc
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.
Escape character is '^]'.

Which terminates the session instead of process xyz , what is other way i also tried

telnet 0 xyz < test
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection to 0 closed by foreign host.

Answer (score 1):

telnet does not process standard input and standard output.

You should check other programs like 'expect'.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of the expect command but unfortunately expect is not installed on my server , i would like to explore other options

Comment: Hi , Could anyone please help me with this .. I am able to capture the error which the command produces using the &> option but not able to get the output , any help would be useful

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using nc (netcat) instead of telnet works nicely for simple commands:

```
echo "command to send"|nc host 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `eval`:

```
eval "{ echo; 
        sleep 5;
        echo 'xvz'; 
        sleep 10; }" | telnet your_host
```

Use `sleep`s to keep open the connection; try different delay times.

Comment: Why the eval? It works fine without it...

Answer (score 0):

`echo` the command(s) you want to send, then use `cat` to keep the connection open.

```sh
{ echo "commands to send"; cat -; } | telnet localhost 8080
```

While the connection is open, you can type commands as usual, but you cannot send the escape character to telnet.

To close the connection, press Ctrl+C.